# access map in vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

Does anyone know how I can access map key/value when the map is in the vector?

```
struct ControlPointSet
{
  std::map<uint32_t,uint32_t> control_points;
}
```

When the vector look like this:

```
void someMethod(const std::vector<ControlPointSet>& controlpoint_sets)
{
  //run through the map vector
  for(auto it = controlpoint_sets.begin(); it != controlpoint_sets.end(); it++)
     {
         for(int i = 0; i < it->control_points.size(); i ++)
         {
             std::cout << it->control_points.at(i) << std::endl;
         }
}
```

Somehow this is not working

Comment: `controlpoint_sets` or `controlpoint_set`?

Comment: What are the values in the map? It looks like you're treating it like it has key/val pairs for all keys in [0, map.size())...is this true? Also what does "somehow this is not working" mean?

Comment: "Somehow this is not working" What does it mean? Do you get a compiler error? Runtime error? Expected output does not match real output? Please provide us with more details.

Comment: A `map`'s `at` takes a key, not an index. If your keys aren't sequential, your inner loop is meaningless. If they are, why aren't you using a vector of vectors?

Comment: The vector is filled with points soo there are values inside, @StephenM.Webb the method controlpoint_set

Comment: Use an `iterator` to iterate through the map, not indexes, eg: `for(auto cp = it->control_points.begin(); cp != it->control_points.end(); ++cp) { std::cout << cp->first << " " << cp->second << std::endl; }`

Comment: @Joha A map is a terrible way of representing a set of points. I think you want a `std::vector<std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>>`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yeah i know but my assignment dont let me do that so i must use the terrible map ...

Comment: @RemyLebeau ahh okey thanks!

Comment: is `control_points` really the only member of `ControlPointSet` ? If so, why dont you use a plain map? Also `ControlPointSet` is a bad name for something that is not a set but a map...

Comment: Great choice of name... I can't believe nobody thought of it before!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a `std::map`'s elements by index.  Its `at()` method takes a key as input instead.

You can use an `iterator`:

```
void someMethod(const std::vector<ControlPointSet>& controlpoint_sets)
{
    //run through the elements of the vector
    for(auto it = controlpoint_sets.begin(); it != controlpoint_sets.end(); ++it)
    {
        //run through the elements of a map
        for(auto cp = it->control_points.begin(); cp != it->control_points.end(); ++cp)
        {
            std::cout << cp->first << " " << cp->second << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Or a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
void someMethod(const std::vector<ControlPointSet>& controlpoint_sets)
{
    //run through the elements of the vector
    for(const auto &cps : controlpoint_sets)
    {
        //run through the elements of a map
        for(const auto &cp : cps.control_points)
        {
            std::cout << cp.first << " " << cp.second << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest you not encourage OP to use initials as variable names, so `cps` ->`control_point_set`  and `cp` to `control_point` or `point`. You could also suggest OP use structured binding for iterating the internal map.